# string comparison to integer is inconsistent in different versions

Tags: php, php-7.4, php-8

I am currently using `PHP8` and stumbled upon a situation while handling an `API request` sending the `string: [object Object]` in a comparison of `$string > 0`, I've tried to test different comparisons using `PHP8` and `PHP7.4`:

```
                                    PHP8     |  PHP7.4
var_dump('[object Object]' > 0);    //true   |  //false
var_dump('[object Object]' > -1);   //true   |  //true
var_dump('[object Object]' > 1);    //true   |  //false
var_dump('[object Object]' === 0);  //false  |  //false
var_dump('[object Object]' == 0);   //false  |  //true
var_dump('[object Object]' < 0);    //false  |  //false
var_dump('[object Object]' < -1);   //false  |  //false
var_dump('[object Object]' < 1);    //false  |  //true
```

I've only lately upgraded to `PHP8`, and this is confusing me a lot for why did it even change?

I only used loose comparison of `string ~ integer`, but now I feel forced to just use `ctype_* functions` to verify values;

Is there something that I missed while migrating from `PHP7.4` to `PHP8` about loose comparisons?

**(I do understand that currently `string > integer` will always result in `true`, but I am not sure if this change is permanent or will change again or I missed something)**

Comment: I think this has what you are looking for: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison

Comment: @ChrisHaas I really don't get how the comparison operator `<` and `=` are different with strings to integer, so I don't totally get the reason in the link.

Comment: Per that RFC, when a string is compared with a number, the number is converted to a string. The string `0` is ASCII 0x48, which gets compared to the first character in `[object Object]` which is `[`, and that is ASCII 0x91, so it is greater. If instead you compared with `!`, which is ASCII 0x33, the `0` would be greater. You can see that here: https://3v4l.org/2MdmD

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php